# Python - Send Integer or String to Spark-Streaming

Tags: python, sockets, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I can send my data through CSV file. First, write my random numbers into CSV file then send it, but is it possible to send it directly?
my socket code:

```
import socket
host = 'localhost'
port = 8080

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)
while True:
    print('\nListening for a client at',host , port)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('\nConnected by', addr)
    try:
        print('\nReading file...\n')
        while 1:
            out = "test01"
            print('Sending line', line)
            conn.send(out)
    except socket.error:
        print ('Error Occured.\n\nClient disconnected.\n')
conn.close()
```

spark streaming code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

sc = SparkContext("local[2]","deneme")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)
socket_stream = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",8080)

random_integers = socket_stream.window( 30 )

digits = random_integers.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda digit: (digit, 1))

digit_count = digits.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)
digit_count.pprint()

ssc.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because socket blocks sending the data and never moves on. The most basic solution is to send some amount of data and close the connection:

```
import socket
import time

host = 'localhost'
port = 50007

i = 0

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)

try:
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        try:
            for j in range(10):
                conn.send(bytes("{}\n".format(i), "utf-8"))
                i += 1
                time.sleep(1)
            conn.close()
        except socket.error: pass
finally:
    s.close()
```

To get something more interesting check non-blocking mode with timeouts.

Comment: Is there any faster way to do that? Because each time opening and closing the connection wastes a lot of time.