# Python - Stream - How to send data to server faster

Tags: python, sockets, apache-spark, stream, spark-streaming

I want to send strings from a text file to my local port but i have to open connection and close it for each string. Therefore, data flow is very slow.(Almost in two seconds 1 string). How can i make it faster?

```
        while 1:
            conn, addr = s.accept()

            line_number = random.randint(1,2261074)
            liste.append(line_number)
            line = linecache.getline(filename,line_number)

            sendit = line.split("   ")[1]
            print type(sendit)
            print "sending: " + sendit
            conn.send(sendit)

            conn.close()
            print('End Of Stream.')
```

Comment: The main factor which slows the sending down is that you always open new connections. This is heavily limited by network latency. Thus a major speedup is only possible if you abandon this concept and always use the same TCP connection. But *"I have to open connection and close it for each string"* suggests that you must adhere to this behavior. In this case: no major speedup possible.

Comment: Actually my main purpose is to send data into my port but spark streaming were couldn't recieve the datas. So, here, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726552/python-send-integer-or-string-to-spark-streaming) they suggest me to open and close the connection each time.

Comment: You have tried opening once, sending everything, and then closing. Now you are opening and closing after sending each string. Is there some way that you can open and close the connection after every N number of rows are sent?

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726552/python-send-integer-or-string-to-spark-streaming) suggests sending 10 messages to Spark on each connection, separating each message by 1 second, then closing the connection.

It might be better to keep the connection open and use a non-blocking socket at the server end.

The server code below keeps the connection open, sending messages in batches on a non-blocking socket, with an idle delay between each batch.

This can be used to test how fast Spark can receive messages. I've set it to send in batches of 50 messages, then wait 1 second before sending the next 50.

Spark receives all messages OK on my machine, even if I set the idle delay to zero.

You can experiment and adjust as needed for your application.

Server code:

```
import socket
import time
import select

def do_send(sock, msg, timeout):
    readers = []
    writers = [sock]
    excepts = [sock]
    rxs, txs, exs = select.select(readers, writers, excepts, timeout)
    if sock in exs:
        return False
    elif sock in txs:
        sock.send(msg)
        return True
    else:
        return False

host = 'localhost'
port = 9999

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)

print "waiting for client"
conn, addr = s.accept()
print "client connected"
conn.setblocking(0)

batchSize = 50
idle = 1.
count = 0
running = 1
while running:
    try:
        sc = 0
        while (sc < batchSize):
            if do_send (conn, 'Hello World ' + repr(count) + '\n', 1.0):
                sc += 1
                count += 1
        print "sent " + repr(batchSize) + ", waiting " + repr(idle) + " seconds"
        time.sleep(idle)
    except socket.error:
        conn.close()
        running = 0

print "done"
```

Simple Spark code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

sc = SparkContext("local[2]","test")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
ststr = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
lines = ststr.flatMap(lambda line: line.split('\n'))
lines.pprint()
ssc.start()  
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Hope this may be useful.

Comment: Nope, this one, also, is not working. First it's not look like streaming. When i print the streamed data. It printed from the first data till the last one. But actually spark has to print only the data arrived in specific interval time.

Secondly, map is not working in that line, `lines = ststr.flatMap(lambda line: line.split('\n')).map(lambda x: (x,1))`

Comment: @osman tamer well, it works for me (but that doesn't help you I know). If you want more assistance you'll need to post your complete code for someone to take a look at, not just the while 1: snippet, and explain what outcome you are seeking.